# Reshape 5D array to 2D array

Tags: numpy, reshape

I have an array with this shape (26, 396, 1, 1, 6) which I want to convert into this shape (10296, 6) meaning that I want to stack the 396 arrays on top of each other.

I tried:

```
a = b.reshape(26*396,6)
```

but this does not "stack" them correctly. I want (1, 396, 1, 1, 6) to be the first 396 arrays of the new array, (2, 396, 1, 1, 6) to be the next 396 arrays of the array, (3, 396, 1, 1, 6) the next and so on.

Comment: what is the correct way then?
Can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have tried to provide more information - its difficult with such a large array. Is it helpful?

Comment: have you tried    a = b.transpose(1, 0, 2, 3, 4).reshape(-1, 6)    ?

Comment: Can you please add a [**Minimal** Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is to concatenate the second axis down using [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
>>> np.concatenate(x, 1).reshape(-1, 6)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
>>> np.hstack(x).reshape(-1, 6)
```

Alternatively, as noted by [@Yann Ziselman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15306606/yann-ziselman) in the comments, you can swap the first two axes before reshaping to the final form:

```
x.swapaxes(0,1).reshape(-1, 6)
```

---

Here is a minimal example:

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(3, 4, 1, 1, 3)
array([[[[[0.66762863, 0.67280411, 0.8053661 ]]],


        [[[0.55051478, 0.79648146, 0.66660467]]]],



       [[[[0.58070253, 0.76738551, 0.30835528]]],


        [[[0.10904043, 0.13234366, 0.25146988]]]]])


>>> np.hstack(x).reshape(-1, 3)
array([[0.66762863, 0.67280411, 0.8053661 ],
       [0.58070253, 0.76738551, 0.30835528],
       [0.55051478, 0.79648146, 0.66660467],
       [0.10904043, 0.13234366, 0.25146988]])

>>> np.reshape(-1, 3) # compared to flattening operation
array([[0.66762863, 0.67280411, 0.8053661 ],
       [0.55051478, 0.79648146, 0.66660467],
       [0.58070253, 0.76738551, 0.30835528],
       [0.10904043, 0.13234366, 0.25146988]])
```

Comment: That gives me: a= np.concatenate(stress_tensors_to_append.view(-1,6))
ValueError: Type must be a sub-type of ndarray type

Comment: @AsbjoernLund Use `np.reshape` instead of `np.view`.

Comment: @Ivan what is the difference between your answer and what OP's doing supposed to be?
It looks exactly the same but you use more code and thus less efficient.

Comment: @yannziselman See my edit above, the concatenation was meant to be on `axis=1`, not `axis=0`.

Comment: @Ivan will it be the same as     a = b.transpose(1, 0, 2, 3, 4).reshape(-1, 6)    ?

Comment: @yannziselman Indeed it will. And actually you can get away with `np.swapaxes`: `x.swapaxes(0,1).reshape(-1, 6)`